# How to raise ButtonClick event by using mnemonic of a label?

Tags: c#, button, event-handling, label

In my C# app I have a label with a mnemonic (e.g. &Path) and a button. I want to raise ButtonClick event when user presses mnemonic for the label (e.g. [Alt] and then [P]). But I haven't found any label event to handle this situation. Using OnFocus event of a button is not an option, as user may use [Tab] key to navigate.

So is there a way to achieve what I want?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have u tried to set the OnClick event of the label and there call the button click?

Comment: Yes, but mnemonic doesn't raise OnClick event of a label.

Comment: yes you are right, mnemonic doesn't raise the OnClick event

Comment: Hmmm so what does the mnemonic on a Label do then?

Comment: It moves focus to the next control, according to TabIndex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

or you can just name your button with something that starts with the litter `p` and then put `&` before it, the `alt + p` will trigger the `btn_Click` event handler

Edit:
What about something like this :)
[image]

Comment: Perfectly :) That's what I wanted. Thanks a lot. By the way in this case the TabIndex of button must  be less than the label's.

Comment: No need, all what matters is do not make your `browse btn` the first focused control in your form.

Comment: That's an interesting way to deal with it but now the button can't have a useful mnemonic anymore.  It's bound to mimic what the label wants to do.

Comment: In my case that is what I want - make the button do what label says.

Answer (score 1):

Mnemonics on labels only gives focus to the control that has the next `TabIndex` and that's all it does.  You cannot use it to directly invoke anything (such as the click event of a button).

You can use the knowledge of this behavior to simulate what you want to achieve.  The idea is to place a lightweight, focusable control on your form that has a `TabIndex` that immediately follows the label but in a location that it is not visible (like the beyond the upper left corner).  Then do what you will on that hidden control's focus events.

Here's a complete standalone example.  In this case, the hidden control will be a check box.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class MyForm : Form
{
    public MyForm()
    {
        targetLabel = new Label()
        {
            Text = "&Label",
            TabIndex = 10,
            AutoSize = true,
            Location = new Point(12, 17),
        };
        // you don't need to keep an instance variable
        var hiddenControl = new CheckBox()
        {
            Text = String.Empty,
            TabIndex = 11,                    // immediately follows target label
            TabStop = false,                  // prevent tabbing to control
            Location = new Point(-100, -100), // put somewhere not visible
        };
        hiddenControl.GotFocus += (sender, e) =>
        {
            // simulate clicking on the target button
            targetButton.Focus();
            targetButton.PerformClick();
        };
        targetButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "&Click",
            TabIndex = 20,
            AutoSize = true,
            Location = new Point(53, 12),
        };
        targetButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Target Clicked!");
        };
        dummyButton = new Button()
        {
            Text = "&Another Button",
            TabIndex = 0,
            AutoSize = true,
            Location = new Point(134, 12),
        };
        dummyButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Another Button Clicked!");
        };

        this.Controls.Add(targetLabel);
        this.Controls.Add(hiddenControl);
        this.Controls.Add(targetButton);
        this.Controls.Add(dummyButton);
    }
    private Label targetLabel;
    private Button targetButton;
    private Button dummyButton;

    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        Application.Run(new MyForm());
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You didnt specify type of your project (Winforms/WPF) but I think the solution would be same for all this types:
You should set `KeyPreview` on your form to true and check pressed keys in `KeyUp` event handler as nelow:

```
    private void Form1_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.KeyCode == Keys.P && e.Alt == true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Got it");
        }
    }
```

In this sample you would get message box in case of Alt+P pressed

Comment: he needs the `Alt` key, i guess

Comment: @Rami.Shareef: this not sufficient in the sample, I have edited my ansewr, so now its for Alt key :)

Comment: That is not actually what I need. In your example both Alt and P should be pressed, whereas to use mnemonic (it's not hotkey) user presses Alt, releases it and then presses P.

Comment: @Dmitry Erokhin: This question for person who downvoted :) I know that it wasnt you